# Git problems with creating folders and seeing them in Windows Explorer and accessing them (Weird Adobe Aero Lnk in File Directory too)

Tags: windows, git, command-line, adobe, explorer

When I do the MKDIR (Skillspire HTML CSS Javascript) it works in Gitbash but doesn't show up on Windows File Explorer.  Then it does access denied to go to it through GitBash.  Should I try to have only one terminal open or do a 2nd virtual desktop on Windows 11?
Or is it some setting in Windows Pro or Tools?

I just started a Tech BootCamp for Python Full Stack.  The instructor has been teaching 2 years and has a Macbook but most of us have Windows (Mine's Samsung Book2 Pro).

I get a weird directory showing Adobe Aero lnk also.  Is there a conflict?  I'm using also all the advanced settings to see everything for developer options in File Explorer.

Help>

Comment: Git doesn't "do" folders in commits, and `mkdir` in bash (whether it's installed as git-bash, or regular bash) is not a Git command. When you do work in your working tree, you use ordinary non-Git commands to work with ordinary non-Git files and non-Git folders in the ordinary non-Git working tree folder. In other words, coming at this as if it's a Git issue means you're on the wrong track: it has nothing to do with Git.

Comment: I get it.  Git is just a Linux CUI or Terminal for my computer.  I found the problem.  Windows 11 has the desktop in the cloud with OneDrive.  So I had to cd onedrive then cd desktop then cd "whatever folder I want".  Same for touch/mkdir.  or ls .. @torek

Comment: Don't put Git repositories into cloud-synced folders. The syncing software winds up damaging them (usually not until right before some important demo or whatever, per Murphy's Laws).